# PHP - get array records by index range

Tags: php, arrays

HI there,

Is there any PHP native function which returns the range of records from the array based on the start and end of the index?

i.e.:

```
array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd');
```

and now I would like to only return records between index 1 and 3 (b, c, d).

Any idea?

Comment: this question is synonymous with "PHP array_slice" http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 30):

Couldn't you do that with e.g. [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)?

```
$a = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd');
array_slice($a, 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 15):

there is a task for [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

`array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )`

example:

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$output = array_slice($input, 2);      // returns "c", "d", and "e"
$output = array_slice($input, -2, 1);  // returns "d"
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"

// note the differences in the array keys
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1));
print_r(array_slice($input, 2, -1, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

By using [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key)

```
$myArray = array(0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'd');
$arrayRange = array('1', '2', '3');

// this can also be used if you have integer only array values
// $arrayRange = range(1,3); 

$newArray = array_intersect_key($myArray, array_flip($arrayRange));

print_r($newArray);  // output: Array ( [1] => b [2] => c [3] => d )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,23,24,26,21,12);

    foreach(range ($array1[0],$array1[5]) as $age){
        echo "Age: {$age}<br />";
    }
```

you should get the following output:

Age: 1

Age: 2

Age: 3

Age: 4

Age: 5

Age: 6

Comment: Downvote.  This is a low-quality answer that will not be portable in non-consecutive cases.  In this [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8b81d0e2d721fdfaede35b520d1304c6d647a6c), you can see that your method fails miserably when there are gaps in the array values.  `range()` fabricates values where there are no values in the array.  Here is the flaw using your own input: [Demo2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5c9f746346168de06cac24c5429dc9a4f00d2d0)  Please delete this answer.  `array_slice()` and `array_intersect_key()` are the most sensible methods.