# Grab every 10 results from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

is there a way to grab the nth 10 results from a PHP array? so like:

an array that contains 200 records and I wanted to pull 10 results from 40 to 50 for example?

Comment: `array_chunk ($array,10);`

Comment: Does your array come from a database? If so you should do this in the query

Comment: Theres a lot of ways to do this. The best way depends on your code and your goal(So should **nth** be random, a percentage, exactly in the middle ,always the same number?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - get array records by index range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715555/php-get-array-records-by-index-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php)

```
$onlyTenResults = array_slice($myArray, 40, 10); // take 10 items starting from 40
```

Comment: oh this is perfectly what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try array_slice()

Example :

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_slice()

This is an example from the PHP manual: [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

**There is only a small issue**

If the array indices are meaningful to you, remember that array_slice will reset and reorder the numeric array indices. You need the preserve_keys flag set to trueto avoid this. (4th parameter, available since 5.0.2).

Example:

```
$output = array_slice($input, 2, 3, true);
Output:

array([3]=>'c', [4]=>'d', [5]=>'e');
```

Comment: Sorry I had tried to made some difference .If you still feel its not different Then i can Delete my answer . Now Thanks

Comment: I'm just asking.you could have chosen a different approach.that too the OP did not even tried.

Comment: I had tried that approach many times .So that's why i thought common approach is better for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

The simple for loop way.

```
$n = 40; 
$num = 10;
$result = [];
for ($i=$n;$i < $n+$nul;$i++) {
   $result[] = $array[$i];
}
print_r($result);
```